# how to run stickies ONLY on desktop space 1

Tags: desktop, spaces

I enjoy using Stickies on Desktop 1.  However, when I switch to Desktop 2 I'd like to have no screen clutter whatsoever.

I can't find a right click option that allows me to Open stickies only on Desktop 1 space.  It seems that whatever option changes I make to stickies, in Desktop 1 or Desktop x, the stickies then uses that option for all desktops.

I'm running Catalina OS, stickies version 10.2

Answer (score 1):

1. Open **Stickies** on the **Desktop** you want the app to only show on. Or, if it's already open, change to the **Desktop** you want to app to only show on.
2. Right-click (or control-click) its **Dock Tile**
3. Mouse over: **Options**
4. Under **Assign To**, click: **This Desktop**, or if you already have numbered **Desktops** showing, then select the one you want it to only show on.

[image]

<sub>The image above is from a default install with additional **Desktops** added but having never selected a specific one for an app yet. You may see menu entries e.g. **Desktop 1**, **Desktop 2**, etc.</sub>

Comment: I don't have a "This Desktop" option.  I have: (1) All Desktops or (2) Desktop on Display 1 (because I have 2 displays) or (3) Desktop on Display 2 or (4) None.   If I select option 2 or option 3 it shows on both desktops!

Comment: @Michael Davis, Please see updated answer. Also, I can not reproduce your issue.  If I select a specific **Desktop** it sticks to it.